# How can I test if a given request parameter is present using Struts tags?

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts, taglib, http-request-parameters

Some pages can receive a certain request parameter called "P1":

```
page.do?P1=value1
```

Right now a scriptlet is testing the existence of the request parameter, and if P1 is "value1" some information is rendered on the page .

Instead of using a scriptlet I want to rewrite this using Struts tags .

Can you please give me some hints on what to use ?

The alternative scriptlet is something like this:

```
<%
String p1 = request.getParameter("P1");
if ("value1".equals(p1)) {
//do something
}
%>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe that you should something like this. This is standard taglib and it is better idea than struts tags

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<c:if test="${not empty param.P1}">
    hello there
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this-

```
<c:if test="${not empty requestScope.P1}" >
```

it would work for me.